# How to show constants in UML CLASS DIAGRAM?

Tags: uml

I can't decide how to show constant class properties in Uml Diagram. Can you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: You also might want to set attribute as static. You could also add a stereotype "constant" and or a tagged value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd323861.aspx shows also a "read only" option for the Microsoft UML tool

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
CONSTANT_NAME : constant_type = value
```

E. g.:

```
PI : double = 3.1415
```